# Issue with redundant SSO permissions prompts; workflow for Apps Marketplace install

Tags: single-sign-on, google-apps-marketplace

I've been working over the past month with a Google support rep, who's responsible for validating SSO workflow/integration for Google App Marketplace submissions. We have everything setup, configured, and tested successfully -- with the exception of one mysterious issue. My Google rep recommended I post our issue here, as both he and I are unsure how to resolve it.

When you install our app (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/floruit-labs-pond/bhalfbanckpdhnkjnknlhcoiohcigocm?hl=en), the workflow prompts you more than once to allow permissions. Which of course is a deal-breaker for getting published in the Marketplace.

At the risk of over sharing, I'm attaching background materials for context: [screenshots of our install workflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKzCG.png)

Also, copied below is the snippet of code embedded in our login page -- that adds the Google login button functionality:

```html
<!---include Google Apps SSO scripts --->
<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="743379733841-bt8rpjio0qs44kei4vlk5av888fbp0fs.apps.googleusercontent.com">
 <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer>

<!---include Google Apps SSO button --->
          <div class="g-signin2" data-theme="dark" data-width="250" data-height="52" data-longtitle="true" align="left" style="margin-top:50px;"></div>
    <script>
      function onSignIn(googleUser) {
        // Useful data for your client-side scripts:
        var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
        console.log("ID: " + profile.getId()); // Don't send this directly to your server!
        console.log("Name: " + profile.getName());
        console.log("Image URL: " + profile.getImageUrl());
        console.log("Email: " + profile.getEmail());

        // The ID token you need to pass to your backend:
        var id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
        console.log("ID Token: " + id_token);
      };
        function renderButton() {
      gapi.signin2.render('my-signin2', {
        'scope': 'profile email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
        'longtitle': true,
        'theme': 'dark',
        'onsuccess': onSuccess,
        'onfailure': onFailure
      });
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Sign-in/OAuth2 dialog won't auto-approve if it contains additional scopes that the user or admin hasn't approved. The Google Sign-in button appears to always be including the "openid" scope, which isn't one of the scopes your application is configured for. Please add that scope to your Apps Marketplace configuration and it should resolve the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. I can't find any documentation that shows the scope URL for OpenID. Can you confirm what URL to enter into our Apps Marketplace SDK configuration page?

Comment: The Open ID scope is the literal string "openid". You can determine the scopes being requested by inspecting the URL of the authorization dialog that the Google Sign-in button launches.

Comment: Hi - I'm returning to this effort after a couple months. Thanks for your (4/19) response, however the addition of the Openid scope is still not clear...or working. To clarify, I need to add this scope within our Google Developer API Manager (selecting to configure our settings for the App Marketplace SDK), correct? Or are you suggesting I add the scope directly within my code (for the button, in my login page)?

Comment: To add to my last comment, if I'm supposed to be adding the openid scope within the API Manager, I've tried adding it within the Oauth 2.0 Scopes section...but keep hitting an "invalid scope URL" error. I've tried: